# Table header background image doesn't work in CSS file

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why doesn't the background-image attribute work from the CSS file but works if I use it in the 'style' within the 'th' tag of my table??

```
 table .header {
   background-image: url('Images/bg.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-top: 8px;
   height: auto;
}
```

EDIT: my example table:

```
               <table id="exampletable" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>head1</th>
                            <th>heade2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>body1</td>
                            <td>body2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>body3</td>
                            <td>body4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

and I linked the css file in the site.master (I'm in asp web app)

Comment: How did you link the `css` file?

Comment: `<link href="content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Image path should be relative to the css's location

Comment: Please show just your table and header part of your design

Comment: Check the path of images, is correct in this scenario also, however you can check by debugging it that image is loading or not

Comment: i've added the table code in the first post

Comment: there is no class by name header given in html

Comment: There's you problem no class called `header`. Change to `<thead class="header">` and maybe remove `table` from your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `../` before Images

```
table .header {
   background-image: url('../Images/bg.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-top: 8px;
   height: auto;
}
```

If `Images` and `content` are side by side in a folder

Comment: ive tryed: `/Images/bg.png` and `~/Images/bg.png` but still don't work

Answer (score 0):

Is "header" the class of your table?  In that case, there will be no space between them in your css:

```
table.header {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose this is your table, `<th>` is your `header`

```
<table border="1">
   <th>Column 1</th>
   <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

use this kind of css:

```
th{
   background-image: url('Images/bg.png'); //or ('../Images/bg.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-top: 8px;
   height: auto;
}
```

See [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/zgX9m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a class like in my example and then call in your css

```
<table id="exampletable" class="tablesorter">
                        <thead class="sample">
                            <tr>
                                <th>head1</th>
                                <th>heade2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>body1</td>
                                <td>body2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>body3</td>
                                <td>body4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>


.sample {
   background-image: url('Images/bg.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-top: 8px;
   height: auto;

}
```